# How can I send real-time data using Django WebSockets?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, websocket, django-channels

I would like to send real-time data from external API using Django WebSockets. My view with HTTP looks in this way:

```
@permission_classes([GetPermission])
class DataList(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = ObjectSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        parameter = self.request.query_params.get('parameter', None)
        queryset = ExternalAPI().get(parameter, "RSQA")
        id = Object.objects.get(parameter=parameter).id
        queryset["id"] = id
        return Response(queryset)
```

I would like use WebSockets instead of HTTP to send my data constantly. Is it a good solution and acceptable to send it without request? I wonder how it should be done? I will be grateful if example would be shown on my `GenericAPIView`.

Comment: What do you mean by real time?

Comment: @Rob Data is sent, for example, every second.

Answer (score 0):

Django is synchronous by nature and hence by itself it was/is not possible to achieve web sockets. However one of the core developers of django(I believe its Andrew Goodwin, correct me if its wrong!) developed [channels](https://github.com/django/channels) for this purpose. Channels although was supposed to be part of django, now its a django project but seperate from the framework. 
I have tried channels once long back when it just came out. Its fine little thing, though you should know its philosophy as I quote.

> Channels is deliberately designed to prefer low latency (goal is a few
>   milliseconds) and high throughput over guaranteed delivery, which
>   doesn’t match some message queue designs.
>
> Some features, like guaranteed ordering of messages, are opt-in as
>   they incur a performance hit, but make it more message queue like.

If this does not sound like what you want, go for something like [django-websocket-redis](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis).

Comment: Yes, I wrote that I am going to use websockets (Django Channels). However I have no idea how should my consumer etc. looks like and I hope that someone show me solution or tips.